# My character struggles to walk up on stairs in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm not using `CharacterController` since it won't give me the whole control to its physics. I'm moving my character with `AddForce` method. I have stairs in my game which have mesh collider with `convex` enabled. So, collider looks like a ramp but my character struggles to walk up on it and if I stop moving in middle of the stairs, character starts sliding down. this is how I'm moving my character:

```
float horizontal;
float vertical;

void Update(){
    horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    MovePlayer();
}

private void MovePlayer()
{
    moveDirection = playerrb.transform.forward * vertical + playerrb.transform.right * horizontal;
    if(isGrounded){
        playerrb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f, ForceMode.Force);
    }else{
        playerrb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f * 0.2f, ForceMode.Force);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sliding is the easier thing to fix, so I'll start with that.
While you are considered grounded you can simply disable gravity for your player.

```csharp
if(isGrounded){
  playerrb.useGravity = false;
  playerrb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f, ForceMode.Force);
}else{
  playerrb.useGravity = true;
  playerrb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f * 0.2f, ForceMode.Force);
}
```

Sometimes this is also enough to allow to ascend on steeper slopes like your stairs (up to 60° should be possible), but if that is not sufficient you'll  need to adjust the force direction to be parallel with the ground using the normal of the surface.

```csharp
Vector3 newForceDirection = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.Cross(surfaceNormal, moveDirection), surfaceNormal);
```

Note that the cross product has to be in this exact order or you'll end up with a vector that moves you backwards.

The exact methodology to acquire normal depends on your game.